# How to make remote desktops (Citrix) with resolutions above the native resolution work with Ubuntu?

Tags: display-resolution

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my HP laptop (Model - G8D85PA).

At present there is only one display resolution listed in System Settings --> Display with resolution 1366 X 768.

I want to install other resolutions also. I am connecting to my office desktop through Citrix receiver and my office's desktop is running on other display configuration and I need to install that display resolution in my ubuntu 14.04 to get it working with my office desktop.

I have checked from admin login, only one display resolution is getting listed.

Please advice how can I install other display resolutions. Also if anyone knows from which site can I install display driver for HP, if needed.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers for how to install additional drivers for your AMD graphics card. The display resolution depends on the capability of the monitor. Try connecting your laptop to a bigger monitor and see if you can get better resolution.

Comment: Please add what model graphics card you have to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The [HP Pavilion 15-g009AX (G8D85PA)](http://www.91mobiles.com/hp-15-g009ax-g8d85pa-apu-quad-core-4-gb-1-tb-dos-laptop-price-in-india-65614) seems to ship with a built in display/panel with 1366x768 pixels native resolution. It wouldn't make sense to try forcing it into outputting a higher resolution. It would either fail to display anything at all or resize and make the image appear blurry.

- If you really need a higher resolution to be able to work with your corporate desktop, you should attach an external monitor with a higher native resolution, as already suggested.
- Alternatively – or better said, try this first – you should try to set the display size/resolution for this remote connection as described in the [product documentation](http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/xenapp5fp-w2k8/ps-sf-ica-display-config-v2.html). As Citrix solutions usually use ICA files – which are just plain text files – you can edit a copy of the ICA file and enter a custom resolution that fits your screen. I don't remember the exact lines, but looking at some [forum posts](http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/43725-resolution-in-ica-client/), you should look for something similar to this:

  ```
  DesiredHRES=1024
  DesiredVRES=768
  ```

  This is usually not a big deal and as far as I can remember you can use any display size and aspect ratio, the same goes for RDP connections.

If you use a way of connecting to the remote desktop where you don't/shouldn't have access to the ICA file, you should file a request to whoever is in charge of this system to be provided with an option that works with your screen size or file a request to get a device that works with the current setup.

(Or replace the panel yourself with another that has a higher native resolution and matches your laptop model, which may also require replacing the internal display cable and probably access to HP support technician tools – that you can find online – to remove firmware warnings about changed hardware.)